# Error while creating django virtual environment

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

When I was trying to create a virtual django env. with "`virtualenv --no-site-packages django`", I was getting error as follows,

```
New python executable in django/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...
  Complete output from command /home/krishna/KRISHN...on/django/bin/python -c "import sys, pip; pip...ll\"] + sys.argv[1:])" setuptools pip:
  Traceback** (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/pip-1.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/pip-1.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/log.py", line 8, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('virtualenv==1.11', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 820, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 988, in create_environment
    install_wheel(to_install, py_executable, search_dirs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 956, in install_wheel
    'PIP_NO_INDEX': '1'
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 898, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /home/krishna/KRISHN...on/django/bin/python -c "import sys, pip; pip...ll\"] + sys.argv[1:])" setuptools pip failed with error code 1***
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446187/no-module-named-pkg-resources

Comment: "Only the latest virtualenv (v1.11) which was released just a few days ago has this problem. Remove the egg from your site-packages folder and install the previous version via easy_install virtualenv==1.10.1, virtualenv will work fine."
see
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20925329/trouble-with-creating-a-virtual-environment-in-windows-8-python-3-3